# javascript scope issue with $.getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, which is loading some javascript and then calling a method from the loaded javascript:

var knackCustomApiLocation = "https://c9.io/xxx/xxx/xx/js/xx.js";

```
  $.getScript(knackCustomApiLocation).done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    alert($.fn.jquery);
createRecords(context);

  })
```

The version prints fine for the first alert, but I also try and print the version in the createRecords method:

```
function createRecords(context){
   alert($.fn.jquery);
   createNewQuotationsForEachUnderwriter(context);
}
```

I get an: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined '

so obviously jquery is not in the scope for the loaded script, but not sure how to fix it so that the called javascript does have access to jquery, and whether or it relates to cross domain issues or not.

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: What method are you using to include jQuery? What is the top-most scope block before global that contains the `$.getScript` method? What does `alert(window.$.fn.jquery)` give you? This is not a cross-domain problem, you can remove that from your title/question.

Comment: jQuery is usually global. What happens if you do `alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);`. If it's a scope issue, you're going to need to provide quite a bit more information that a couple small code fragments.

Comment: How about if you includ the remote script normally and call it in <script> tag, would the problem still persist? Need to make sure it's a scope problem, not some other script overriding JQuery's $.

Comment: Well, the documentation says *"The script is executed in the global context, so it can refer to other variables and use jQuery functions."* so that should not be the problem.

Comment: @KevinB I'm using a 3rd party environment, so not sure how jquery is included. alert(window.$.fn.jquery) gives me: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined...I'm guessing this means that jquery is not global? I'll try setting it global...

Comment: @cookiemonster OK, np, can do. I tried alert(jQuery.fn.jquery); and got: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Comment: what give `alert (typeof window.jQuery)` ?

Comment: And that explains why it doesn't work. the code you are including requires a global jQuery and/or $, which isn't available.

Comment: @KevinB yes, you are right. Thanks for helping me out! I've put an answer below, but suggestions welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help everyone, it was just what I needed.

Yes, looks like given the environment I'm working in, jquery was not defined at the global level. As soon as I defined jquery as a global variable everything worked.

```
   window.$ = $;
```

Not sure if this is the best practice approach however, suggestions welcome!

Comment: the only downside is it could possibly overwrite anything that is currently using `window.$`. Not a whole lot you could do about that though.